# unknown Host exception error [non-duplicate]

Tags: java

Can't resolve this by accepting a server socket like the other person did. (Locks in forever; see comment below]

```
   import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class one_hundred
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       String hostName = "pool-72-83-252-59.washdc.fios.verizon.net";
       int portNumber = 3281;
      try
      {
         /*
         Open a socket.
Open an input stream and output stream to the socket.
Read from and write to the stream according to the server's protocol.
Close the streams.
Close the socket.
*/
         Socket server = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

         OutputStream outToServer = server.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
          out.writeUTF("mJFr1vJBIcpYTtIui6yLrzQw " + server.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = server.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println(in.readUTF());
         server.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

How do I resolve this without ss? (Or somehow solve to socket-locking problem?

An alternative try to this also failed:

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.Socket;
public class onehundred
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
     {String urlParameters = "fName=" + URLEncoder.encode("???", "UTF-8") + "&lName=" + URLEncoder.encode("???", "UTF-8");
        request("http://codeabbey.sourceforge.net", urlParameters);}
public static String request(String gotourl, String urlParameters)
{    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  

     try 
   {     InetAddress locIP = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
     ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 0, locIP);
     //Create connection
    URL url = new URL(gotourl);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("/say-100.php", "Token: 9PaF2QQmZBFX+K3+LlI5ozky");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.close();

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
    { response.append(line);
      response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    System.out.println(response); //System.out.println(line); also prints out nothing
    return response.toString();
   } catch (Exception e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    } finally 
      {
    if(connection != null) 
       {connection.disconnect();}
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The error message says what the problem is. What types are *required* (see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html))? What types are being supplied? Is there a "logical" way to go from supplied->required?

Comment: Obvously `accept()` is a static method. So you need to call the method from an instance of ServerSocket, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines make no sense;

you instanciate a new ServerSocket, but you use the Class to call .accept();

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
ss = ServerSocket.accept();
```

Write this instead:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
Socket socket = ss.accept();
```

Comment: thanks. That resolved the major code problem. Now I just need to get the code to actually do the task...

Comment: can you help me a bit more? Your answer just only got myself into a bigger problem.

Comment: You completely changed the question... Unknown Host means the DNS can't resolve your host `pool-72-83-252-59.washdc.fios.verizon.net`. Try to ping it and check your DNS config.

Answer (score 0):

Post your edit:

The ServerSocket and Socket are completely pointless here. You're making no use of them. Your code will block in `accept()`, possibly forever. Remove them both.

Comment: how are they pointless? if you don't put them there it will say an unknown Host exception error. [see: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/unknownhostexception/java-net-unknownhostexception-how-to-solve-unknownhostexception/--which specifies I must put in "localhost" in order to resolve this error]

Comment: They are pointless in your edited client code, because you aren't using them,